# MPAndroidChart, how to remove decimal percentages and not show percentages below 10?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I have two questions:

- MPAndroid Pie Chart Remove decimal percentages
- Not show values on the Pie Chart that have values less than 10%, but show the slice; just the text should not be shown for the percentages less than 10%.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update for version 3.0.0+**

Formatting values is now done by extending the `ValueFormatter` class and overriding the required methods for formatting. This is also where custom logic (e.g. only show labels for values > 10) can be inserted.

```
class MyValueFormatter : ValueFormatter() {
    private val format = DecimalFormat("###,##0.0")

    // override this for e.g. LineChart or ScatterChart
    override fun getPointLabel(entry: Entry?): String {
        return format.format(entry?.y)
    }
}
```

More examples and a detailed explanation can be found in the [new documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/).

Comment: This is now deprecated in MPAndroidChart 3.0.0

Comment: How to have both Value and Percentage?

Comment: IValueFormatter is deprecated is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

With the new version (3.0.0) of MPAndroidChart, use the following method:

In the `setData()` method:

```
 PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
 data.setValueFormatter(new DecimalRemover(new DecimalFormat("###,###,###")));
```

Here is the DecimalRemover class:

```
public class DecimalRemover extends PercentFormatter {

protected DecimalFormat mFormat;

public DecimalRemover(DecimalFormat format) {
    this.mFormat = format;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
    if(value < 10) return "";
    return mFormat.format(value) + " %";
}
}
```

ValueFormatter has been replaced with PercentFormatter

Comment: getFormattedValue now deprecated

Comment: @NikosHidalgo can you please update the answer with the method that currently would support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

for remove decimal percentages, easily use:
`PiedataSet.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter(new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0")));`

Comment: the PercentFormatter needs a PieChart as a parameter, not a DecimalFormat

Answer (score 0):

**First Step:**
Please put this below "`PercentFormatter`" class in your package folder:

```
public class PercentFormatter extends ValueFormatter {

    public DecimalFormat mFormat;
    private PieChart pieChart;

    public PercentFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##");
    }
    public PercentFormatter(PieChart pieChart) {
        this();
        this.pieChart = pieChart;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        return mFormat.format(value) + " %";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPieLabel(float value, PieEntry pieEntry) {
        if (pieChart != null && pieChart.isUsePercentValuesEnabled()) {
            // Converted to percent
            return getFormattedValue(value);
        } else {
            // raw value, skip percent sign
            return mFormat.format(value);
        }
    }

}
```

**Second Step:**
In your activity where the Piedata set, add value format in the PieDataset that way:

```
 pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
 PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(getData(approved, pending, rejected), "");
 
 pieDataSet.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
 PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
 pieChart.setData(pieData);
```

That way, we can remove the decimal point in the Pie data.