# How to remove the decimal point and retain percentage in PieChart values?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart library to make a pie chart. I would like to display the pie chart values with the decimal. I want to retain the % sign.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440699/5512020) solution to an old similar question is not valid since the release of version 3.0.0 of MPAndroidChart

**UPDATE:**
This is the updated way of removing decimals

```
public class DecimalRemover extends DefaultValueFormatter {
private int digits;

public DecimalRemover(int digits) {
    super(digits);
    this.digits = digits;
}

@Override
public int getDecimalDigits() {
    return digits;
}
}
```

But even if I did `pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);`, the "%" symbol is not being shown

Comment: Why should the solution be invalid? The mentioned functions to set the valueformatter are still in place.

Comment: The interface `ValueFormatter` has been removed

Comment: You're right. I just looked in the javadoc. It is still in there, but it is not used anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `setData()` method:

```
 PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
 data.setValueFormatter(new DecimalRemover(new DecimalFormat("###,###,###")));
```

Here is the DecimalRemover class:

```
public class DecimalRemover extends PercentFormatter {

protected DecimalFormat mFormat;

public DecimalRemover(DecimalFormat format) {
    this.mFormat = format;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
    return mFormat.format(value) + " %";
}
}
```